# Smallest jQuery lightbox script

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, gallery

What's the smallest lightbox plugin for jQuery (in terms of size)? Something close to [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), but smaller :)

Comment: The smallest one will always be the one you build yourself, since plugin builders need to accommodate for a wider range of users than a single person.

Comment: create a detailed specification and we can codegolf :)

Comment: Adding to what Yi Jiang said, what browsers are you planning to support? going to have images (for shadows and corners) or going to use CSS3?

Comment: What functionality, features do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this sometime ...

http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2

It's only 4K .

Comment: But Slimbox 2 is not fit for responsive sites.

Comment: it is actually about 40 kB (or 6.4 kB without jQuery).

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a low-level jQuery lightbox script called **Nitelite**: https://github.com/premasagar/nitelite (it's 1.4KB when minified and gzipped)

It is the kind of thing that can be either used on its own, or to build more feature-rich lightbox plugins.

It's been used in production on a couple of projects:

- the BBC World Service widget (click a news article): http://www.bbc.co.uk/persian/services/2009/05/090512_pm_widget_conditions.shtml
- the MiShorts widget (click a film thumbnail): http://www.mishorts.com/widget

It's open source, MIT license. Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Yi Jiang already stated, the "smallest" depends completely on your specific needs, if you want everything that Fancybox does, I hardly doubt that there's a way around using that very plugin.

Still you could take a look at others and see whether they fit your needs, you should check out this [list of lightbox scripts](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts), many of which are smaller in size than Fancybox, but you'll still have to evaluate them and see if they fit your needs.

And last but not least you can always write your own one by reading a [tutorial](http://dryan.com/articles/posts/2009/5/6/jquery-lightbox-tutorial/). That is, if you want to write your own one. But then again, if you have such specific needs you *should* know that nobody will come along and write some code for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to these sort of problems is to find a script that meets my requirements then hack it mercilessly until it only contains what I need. Once that's achieved, I'll minify the script (leaving the compression of the script up to my server).

While we're on the subject, if you are looking for small scripts mainly to reduce the browser fetch time, then also ensure that your web server cache control headers and compression settings are set to good values. A nice writeup (regarding caching) can be found [here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html).  If you don't have a good caching policy defined, then it won't matter much whether the script is small if it is being downloaded from the server on every page view.

Answer (score 0):

I would shy away from the PrettyPhoto plugin, which appears convenient. There is an advertisement on their demo which is suspicious (my site was redirected shortly after experimenting with it)

If you are looking for a lightbox, try to find one that has been updated to the latest query. Slimbox2 and fancy box have not been updated for modern css, using images to build the box, and neither have been updated for streamlining changes in the latest jquery.