# Alert window when making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I make an ajax call to a servlet's post method from my js file. 
I wish to show an alert box till I get a response back. 
How can i do it using ajax.

The alert window should close after I get response automatically.
ajax post request

```
    $.post(fullpath, function(data) {
        fnBookTicket(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a popup DIV instead and then close it...

CSS

```
 div#popup { display: none; position: absolute; width: 200px; height 100px; 
     top: 50%; left:50%; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -100px; 
     background: white; border: 1px solid blue; z-index: 9999 }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="popup">Alert! Loading...</div>
```

JS

```
  $('div#popup').show();
  $.post(fullpath, function(data) {  
    $('div#popup').hide();
    fnBookTicket(data); 
  });
```

The popup shows before the ajax call and hides in the success handler, that is when data is loaded...

Comment: sorry, I am a newbie to ajax where do i add this show() in the ajax post. i do see the response part

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.. You **cannot close** the alert window using any event..

You need to explicitly close it by clicking on it..

Try showing a div or a popup on which you have more control..

You can also use the [blockUI jQuery](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) Plugin

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a lightbox script to create a modal dialog that floats over the page until your resource is returned.  Then, remove it.  The `alert` box cannot be closed programmatically - it must be closed by the user.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653841/smallest-jquery-lightbox-script) are some good choices for lightweight lightbox scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close an alert box that way. Use a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) instead.